# TextBox control validation not working well inside TabItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

I have textbox with validation error template inside TabItem.

Problem is when I try to switch between tabs, Validation is getting disappeared. I tried to search and found it is a bug and to make validation  work fine, need to wrap DxTabItem content inside AdornerDecorator

So Xaml will look like this.

```
<TabItem>
<AdornerDecorator>
<StackPanel>
<Textbox/>
</StackPanel>
</AdornerDecorator>
</TabItem>
```

I want to make it in common place so i don't need to do same in all screens.

Could you give me an example which shows how I can do this in one place.

Thanks,

Comment: I had the same issue . Try putting AdornerDecorator out of your tab control, in another word, put your tab control inside AdornerDecorator

Comment: @Jamaxack I know that will work but I dont want to put in all my screens,better I inherit TabItem and do at common place. I am looking for common solution.